# Why doesn't typescript narrow types with control flow and never when using arrow functions

Tags: typescript, type-narrowing

Typescript refuses to narrow with a call to `fail` but will narrow with a call to `fail2`. Is this a bug in typescript?

```js
const fail = (message?: string): never => {
    throw new Error(message);
};

function fail2(message?: string): never {
    throw new Error(message);
}

const getData = (): string | null => {
    return "the-data";
}



export const loadDataOrError = (): string => {
    const data = getData();

    if (data === null) {
        // Swap the below and see that it works
         
        // fail2();
        fail();
    }

    // This errors
    return data;
};
```

[here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAZgQwJYBsYF4YAoC2BTCCBAczwH4AuGaAJyTGIEoqw8A3PGjAPhgG8AUDGEwoACxogA7jFYyAojUk1cBIqUYBuAQF9tAuAFcwwKEnDxkKAEyrCJclVr0mLdp35CR4yTLkxFZTt1PC1dAQFQSFhSKAARBCgEDGxmaig6BhgAH1lDFDR0XkERGBo8KEMaMBgAInE8AFoAE0SEWu0dCIi8AA8ABxAaWCjoGBQQBGaEpIB5GkChlKw05yyizwBIUdhWpJTYmYQV-U2kOGw95PQbvILGT1LSgHpnmABlKQR+0TE8GAARngJjIEGBmtQ8P9xIkYEhYFIhgBrCBeJ7CNFPV6WVC2MKbTaIVAnASbLqY8qVaowK6dTRAA) is a playground if you want to try switching the comments and seeing the error vanish.

###### Screenshots for clarity

###### With an error

[image: With an error]

###### Without an error

[image: Without an error]

Comment: Even if `fail` can be reassigned, the new value will still return `never` so that's not a good reason. In your example you are using `as` which is unsound by design, so obviously you can get weird behavior.

Comment: Agreed @GuillaumeBrunerie Also let us not forget that it is a `const` so the whole argument is unsound

Comment: I think you should file an issue. This is not normal.

Comment: Just found [this](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/52784) issue. I guess I'll answer my own question

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to [this](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/52784) open GitHub issue this is a limitation of how type narrowing currently works in typescript. If you want to remedy it you can explicitly annotate arrow function types like so:

```js
const fail: (message?: string) => never = (message) => {
    throw new Error(message)
}
```

Comment: Yeah, it's all about explicit type annotations on the thing you're calling. It's a fairly annoying limitation with assertion functions.